# Regex validation string 4th and 6th special character optional validations

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am trying to make a regex validation and the condition is that, whatever I have typed in 4th character it should same as 6th character from special character(- .) dash or dot

So if I have typed 4th character as - then 6th also must be - and if dot then should be dot.

Also these character can be optional. So If the string don't have 4th character as special character(-.) then 6th also should not be have special character

Note: First 3 character must be number and 5th character also number

For example :

```
123-3- valid
123.4. valid
123-6. invalid
123.7- invalid
1234 valid
12-34 invalid
123.4 invalid
```

What I am trying is below

```
"""(\d{3})[\-.]*(\d{1})[\-.]${'$'}"""
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the pattern with a single optional capture group and an optional backreference, or match 4 digits.

```
^(?:\d{3}([-.])\d\1|\d{4})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `\d{3}([-.])\d\1` Match 3 digits, capture one or `-` or `.` and then match a digit followed by the same captured char using a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1`
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{4}`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIg41Y/1)

Or a bit shorter, matching 3 digits followed by either a digit between the same `.` or `-`, or just a single digit:

```
^\d{3}(?:([-.])\d\1|\d)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y2OGiY/1)

Comment: what \1 means. how to back reference

Comment: @Santhucool The backreference `\1` matches the same character that was matched by the group 1 value, so it can only match either 2 times `.` or 2 times `-` but not `.` and `-` or `-` and `.`

Comment: @ The fourth bird `(\d{3})[\-.]*(\d{3})[\-.]*(\d{4})${'$'}` this is what I trying to achieve. 123-123-1234 -- valid, 123.123.1234 -- valid, 1231231234 -- valid other cases must not be valid. US phone number formating. Can you tell where I did wrong

Comment: @Santhucool You can write is like this with a single capture group `\d{3}([-.])\d{3}\1\d{4}` https://regex101.com/r/MsHoxK/1 and without the `${'$'}` part. To prevent partial matches, you can make use of some sort of boundaries, like for example word boundaries `\b\d{3}([-.])\d{3}\1\d{4}\b`